# How do I run multiple Minecraft server instances on a single physical server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am running a Minecraft server (using Docker) on a physical server. So far, everything's working.

Now I would like to run a second server using a second Docker container, with a different configuration, but on the same physical server. The reason for this is that AFAIK a Minecraft server can only host one world with one configuration, and I'd like to have one server in creative mode, and another one in survival mode.

Now, I need to set up ports for those servers. Is it enough to map port `25565` to another port, and the client is then able to access it, if I provide the IP address / port combination? Or is there anything else I need to watch out for?

Comment: The question as asked has already been answered; I would like to point out that, if you're willing to run a modded server (using Spigot/Paper/etc), you can use a plugin like Multiverse to have multiple worlds with different settings. I do exactly this on my server, with one survival world for normal play and one creative world for my kid to experiment in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should be enough. Also make sure they're running in different folders so they don't try to overwrite each others' files. If you're using plugins with SQL databases, make sure they use different databases. Basically just keep everything separate.

If you don't want the clients to have to type in the port number, you can use a SRV record to give your server a different hostname. (e.g. creative.your-server-name.com)